# DOM Element not accessible from javascript called from GWT native function

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I want to call from GWT a javascript function that accepts element id of element created by UiBinder. Functions fails because it cannot find that element. After some debugging I found this strange behaviour:

```
log.info(DOM.getElementById("MyId").getAttribute("id"));
ScriptInjector.fromString("console.log(document.getElementById(\"MyId\"))").inject();
checkMyId();
log.info(DOM.getElementById("MyId").getAttribute("id"));
```

Results in:

```
MyId
null
null
MyId
```

`checkId` is defined as:

```
public static native void checkMyId()/*-{
    console.log(document.getElementById("MyId"));
}-*/;
```

Both `ScriptInjector` and native functions seems to have limited access to elements compared to `DOM#getElementById`. What is reason for this behaviour? How can I call javascript function so it can access that element?

I've tried using gwt 2.8.0-beta1 and 2.8.0-rc1 with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GWT JSNI Basics](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html)

> When accessing the browser’s window and document objects from JSNI, you must reference them as $wnd and $doc, respectively. Your compiled script runs in a nested frame, and $wnd and $doc are automatically initialized to correctly refer to the host page’s window and document.